# How to load a picture from the resource and html into webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-resources, android-drawable

I want that the webview display the picture from the resource and html code from the database but only the html code from the database works fine.

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
String city = "lichtenstein";
String img = "<img src =\"file://res/drawable/picture.png\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" />";
String dbHTML = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_HTML));
String webdata = "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />" + img + "<br />" + "<span style=\"color:#064896;font-weight:bold;\">" + city  + " </span>" + dbHTML;
wv.loadData(webdata, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

I also tried to use an image from the asset folder but that did not work either.

```
String img = "<img src =\"file:///android_asset/picture.png\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" />";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
String htmlString = <html><body><img src="file.png"></body></html>
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

The first argument, must point where the image must be.

[Source](http://lomza.people.totem-soft.com/?p=62)

Comment: I want to set bg in webview with some html text, is that workable ?